# Помогите доработать код калькулятора выражений в обратной польской записи

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

> Напишите калькулятор выражений в обратной польской записи. В выражении
> должны поддерживаться числа, знаки бинарных операций ‘+’, ‘-’, ‘*’,
> ‘/’. Польская запись записывается в одну строку, причем элементы
> польской записи разделяются произвольным количеством пробелов. Пробелы
> обязательны, когда необходимо отделить два числа друг от друга и
> допускаются для разделения знаков операций друг от друга или знаков
> операций и чисел, а также в начале и конце строки. Гарантируется, что
> польская запись является корректной записью некоторого выражения.
> Пример польской записи:
>
> ```
> 1 2 3 +*
> ```
>
> Числа-операнды записываются в пятеричной симметричной системе
> счисления (см. например, описание троичной симметричной системы
> счисления). В качестве отрицательных цифр пятеричной симметричной
> системы счисления используются цифры B, обозначающая -2, и A,
> обозначающая -1. Таким образом, число B2 в пятеричной симметричной
> системе счисления - это число -8 в десятичной системе счисления.
>
> Калькулятор должен обрабатывать 27-разрядные числа с фиксированной
> точкой, в которых младшие 11 разрядов отводится под дробную часть, а
> старшие 16 разрядов - под целую часть. Например, число 120.0102 в виде
> 27-разрядного числа с фиксированной точкой запишется как
> 000000000000012001020000000.
>
> На вход подаются числа, у которых целая часть отделяется от дробной
> символом “точка”, причем гарантируется, что в целой части числа
> находится не более чем 16 значащих разрядов, а в дробной части - не
> более чем 11 значащих разрядов. У числа с нулевой дробной частью
> дробная часть может отсутствовать.
>
> Ваша программа должна вычислить выражение и вывести результат в виде
> 27-разрядного числа в пятеричной симметричной записи. Если при
> вычислении возникла ошибка, например, результат вычисления операции
> после округления не может быть представлен с требуемой разрядностью,
> должна быть выведена строка ЕRROR.
>
> При вычислении результата операций используйте округление к ближайшему
> представимому значению.

```
polskiu = []
s = input().split()
for x in s:
    if x == '+':
        g = polskiu.pop()
        z = polskiu.pop()
        polskiu.append(g + z)
    elif x == '-':
        g = polskiu.pop()
        z = polskiu.pop()
        polskiu.append(z - g)
    elif x == '*':
        g = polskiu.pop()
        z = polskiu.pop()
        polskiu.append(g * z)
    else:
        polskiu.append(int(x))
print(polskiu[0])
```

НО, у меня не получается вывести результат в виде 27-разрядного числа в пятеричной симметричной записи и сделать обработку ошибки сказанной выше в условии.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input().split()
polskiu = [int(s[0])]

for i in range(len(s) - 2):
    polskiu.append(int(s[i + 1]))
    x = s[-1][i]
    if x == '+':
        g = polskiu.pop()
        z = polskiu.pop()
        polskiu.append(g + z)
    elif x == '-':
        g = polskiu.pop()
        z = polskiu.pop()
        polskiu.append(z - g)
    elif x == '*':
        g = polskiu.pop()
        z = polskiu.pop()
        polskiu.append(g * z)
print(polskiu[0])
```

Comment: спасибо большое, но прочитайте внимательнее предпоследний абзац и поймете в каком виде должен выходить ответ

Comment: и еще насчет ERROR